# How to delete row in a JTable depending upon some text in the row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My code is supposed to compare two JTables and search for specific word in one to the cells.
If the word is found the row should be deleted.
Problem is that, not all the rows are deleted. User has to press several times the delete button to delete all rows.

```
 public class DeleteCleareadTable1Rows extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            int modelIndex = table1.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
            String status = table1.getModel().getValueAt(modelIndex, 9).toString();
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Cleared")) {
                deleteRow(table1, table1Model, i);

            }
        }
    }
}


public static void deleteRow(JTable table, DefaultTableModel model, int rowNo) {
    try{
    model.removeRow(rowNo);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.setModel(model);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException |NullPointerException a){}
}
```

Comment: Do you get Exceptions? Print that, to see whether the 'deleteRow' method is called when you expect. Might help pinpointing the problem

Comment: I donot get any exceptions. Some rows are deleted but not all

Comment: 1. for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for both models in local variable, three short questions 2. extends Thread { ???, 3. (static ???) public static void deleteRow, 3 .  model.fireTableDataChanged(); for DefaultTableModel???

Comment: `model.removeRow(rowNo);` is enough no need for `fireTableDataChanged` and `setModel` after that

Comment: Try using SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait for modifying the model. No need for `fireTableDataChanged` and `setModel` calls.

Comment: See Sarfaraz's answer. Your problem is because you didn't use convertRowIndexToModel method of the JTable.

Answer (score 1):

Try it the other way around

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = table1.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int modelIndex = table1.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
        String status = table1.getModel().getValueAt(modelIndex, 9).toString();
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Cleared")) {
            deleteRow(table1, table1Model, i);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe, but issue can be elsewhere, somewhere in the middle of MilkyWay (based on OPs question and code posted here)

Comment: True, but... If you have 9 rows, delete the first, you have 8 rows, if you then try to delete the 9th row, you get a NullPointer (depending on how it is handled). If you run it the other way around the 'i'th item remains pointing to the right element. Since I'm unclear 'bout JTable itself, I assume the problem is not there

Answer (score 1):

I have faced certain issue when UI doesn't responds well one of issue was realetd with Jtable data and updating it in non swing thread. So you can try putting your code in a Swing thread,precisely  in a Worker thread

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
   for (int i = 0; i < table1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            int modelIndex = table1.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
            String status = table1.getModel().getValueAt(modelIndex, 9).toString();
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Cleared")) {
                deleteRow(table1, table1Model, i);

            }
        }

    return null;
   }
public void deleteRow(JTable table, DefaultTableModel model, int rowNo) {
    try{
    model.removeRow(rowNo);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.setModel(model);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException |NullPointerException a){}
}
  };

  worker.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to delete from 0 to length you'll always have half the rows removed [loop executes 1/2 times only] or some of the rows removed if you've added any condition. And it wont throw any exception.You can see that in the below sample codes and print statements.

```
 //Only half will be removed loop executes n/2 times
 System.out.println("From 0 to n");
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " rowCount = " + model.getRowCount());
            model.removeRow(i);
        }

From 0 to n
i = 0 rowCount = 16
i = 1 rowCount = 15
i = 2 rowCount = 14
i = 3 rowCount = 13
i = 4 rowCount = 12
i = 5 rowCount = 11
i = 6 rowCount = 10
i = 7 rowCount = 9
will stop here
---

//Everything will be removed loop executes n times
System.out.println("From n to 0");
    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i + " rowCount = " + model.getRowCount());
        model.removeRow(i);
    }

From n to 0
i = 15 rowCount = 16
i = 14 rowCount = 15
i = 13 rowCount = 14
i = 12 rowCount = 13
i = 11 rowCount = 12
i = 10 rowCount = 11
i = 9 rowCount = 10
i = 8 rowCount = 9
i = 7 rowCount = 8
i = 6 rowCount = 7
i = 5 rowCount = 6
i = 4 rowCount = 5
i = 3 rowCount = 4
i = 2 rowCount = 3
i = 1 rowCount = 2
i = 0 rowCount = 1
```